# Xcode device list is empty in ionic/cordova project

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ios-simulator

No matter what I try I can't get access to the Xcode simulators from my ionic/cordova project. Xcode Command Line Tool is installed.

```
cordova run ios --list
```

returns

> Available ios devices:
>
> Available ios virtual devices:

```
ionic cordova emulate ios --list
```

returns

> Available ios virtual devices:

I have all the simulators in Xcode and it's working fine when Im opening the project in Xcode and run the simulators manually.

The consequences of this is that I cant run my app with livereload from the terminal:

```
ionic cordova emulate --livereload ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0" --target="iPhone-X, 12.1"
```

returns

> Device id for device name "iPhone X" and runtime "iOS 12.1" could not be found, or is not available.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is a bug related to the new version of XCode. I had the same problem. I would advise you to uninstall and reinstall XCode but I don't think it will work.

I solved (dirty fix) my problem by applying what ejerskov says here: https://github.com/ios-control/ios-sim/issues/246

On `platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/ios-sim/src/lib.js`

I have changed

`available_runtimes[ runtime.name ] = (runtime.availability === '(available)');`

to

`available_runtimes[ runtime.identifier ] = (runtime.availability === '(available)');`

Otherwise I think we should wait for a new release of ios-sim and cordova-ios...

Comment: Worked for me, however it's worth noting that the change to `runtime.identifier` needed to happen at two different locations in `libs.js`...

Comment: This worked for me too. And @DavidM. is right ... it's in 2 places in that lib.js file.